# FACEBOOK MESSENGER APIGRAPH USER PROFILE

Tags: php, laravel, facebook, facebook-graph-api, postman

I hope you can help me

What happens is that I am trying to obtain the name of the user who is sending a message to my facebook page, according to the apigraph documentation it says that it must be something like this
*https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/5?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>*

But at the time of reviewing it in postman it shows me that there is no such user id or that you do not have the necessary permissions
[image]

there is some way to access or what permissions should I request from the api?

Comment: for accessing data of a user, you need to use a user token of that user

Comment: Of each user who sends a message to my page, should I generate a token? The token of the facebook page is not used?

Comment: you cannot just generate a token, the user has to authorize your app for getting a user token and for getting his data with that api call.

Comment: I guarantee `5` is the wrong user ID, unless one of Mark Zuckerberg's friends is messaging you. You can't just make up an ID.

Comment: id 5 was an example only, when the facebook user sends the message I get the user's id

Answer (score 1):

it seems that your **app** is missing some **permissions** in order to get the user profile info make sure that you got approved on these permissions:

- Business Asset User Profile Access*
- pages_user_locale
- pages_user_timezone
- pages_user_gender
- pages_messaging*

Comment: and after you got approved also you need to be "Business verified" to be able to get the data needed you will notice that when YOU use the page its work normally but when normal USER uses it. it get you the code you add.

Comment: I have all these permissions activated and the application accepted, only the verification of the business is waiting, so I'll wait for the verification to be done